# How to set the resource group in MODx plugin?

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I'm using MODx Revolution and I need to set group to resources in my plugin upon saving. But `$modx->newObject()` does not work and resource group isn't set to resources.

This is my code:

```
$id = $resource->get('id');
$group = $modx->newObject('modResourceGroupResource');
$group->set('document', $id);
$group->set('document_group', 5);
$group->save();
```

I save all the data, but resource group is not set to resources. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
// by id
if (!$resource->isMember(123)) {
    $resource->joinGroup(123);
}
// or by name
if (!$resource->isMember('ResourceGroupName')) {
    $resource->joinGroup('ResourceGroupName'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional please see this [Github Issue](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues/4014)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31892257)